# How to add parallax to objects instantiated in play mode and recreated with camera position in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, game-development, unity3d-2dtools

So my endless 2d game has 2 layers of mountains in the background which I want to add parallax on, the Near layer needs to be slower than actor/camera, & the Far to be slowest. The problem is, I can't directly add script of movement to them as they are instantiated in play mode randomly according to the random theme colors, so they are being created one after other from the script below, but I want to add a movement on them on x axis slower than camera speed, while also letting it recreate continuously at the end of last one.

Here's the script creating new mountains :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static PathManager Instance;
public GameObject CoinFragments;
public GameObject SlideArrow;

public float parallaxSpeed = 5f; //

private GameObject lastPathObject;
private float PathXPosition;

private GameObject lastMountainFar;
private float MountainFarXPosition;
private GameObject lastMountainNear;
private float MountainNearXPosition;

private float StarXPostion;

private float lastCameraX;  //

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Instance = this;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}


private void LateUpdate()
{
    // Check for new Near Mountain
    if (lastMountainNear != null && GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x > lastMountainNear.transform.position.x)
    {
        this.GenerateNearMountain();
    }

    // Check for new Far Mountain
    if (lastMountainFar != null && GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x > lastMountainFar.transform.position.x)
    {
        this.GenerateFarMountain();
    }
}



// Start Creating Mountains
public void StartMountainCreation(){
    MountainNearXPosition = GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x;
    MountainFarXPosition = GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x;
    this.GenerateNearMountain();
    this.GenerateFarMountain();
}

private void GenerateNearMountain(){
    Vector3 MountainPosition = new Vector3(MountainNearXPosition - 4f, -3.6f, 10f);
    lastMountainNear = Instantiate(ThemeManager.Instance.SelectedMountainNear, MountainPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    MountainNearXPosition = MountainNearXPosition + lastMountainNear.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x - 0.01f;

    //float deltaX = GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x - lastCameraX;
    //lastCameraX = GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x;
    //lastMountainNear.transform.position += Vector3.right * (deltaX * parallaxSpeed);
}

private void GenerateFarMountain(){
    Vector3 MountainPosition = new Vector3(MountainFarXPosition - 4f, -3.6f, 22f);
    lastMountainFar = Instantiate(ThemeManager.Instance.SelectedMountainFar, MountainPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    MountainFarXPosition = MountainFarXPosition + lastMountainFar.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x - 0.01f;
}
```

Here's my camera movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GamePlayCameraManager : MonoBehaviour {

public static GamePlayCameraManager Instance;   // Singleton Instance
public Camera MainCamera;   // Main Camera

private Vector3 offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Instance = this;
    MainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (GameStateManager.GameState == GameState.Set || GameStateManager.GameState == GameState.Playing)
        MainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(this.offset.x + ActorManager.Instance.Actor.transform.position.x + 0.8f, 0, -10);
}

// Fixed Update Method
void FixedUpdate(){

}

public void FindCameraOffset(){
    this.offset = ActorManager.Instance.Actor.transform.position - MainCamera.transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0f, 0f);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look into [pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling) your mountain objects so you don't waste cpu and memory endlessly creating them.

Once you have them pooled in your `PathManager`, you'll need to first know how far the camera moved in the last frame, and then tell the mountains to move according to that.  You are going to have to have a reference to your `PathManager` in your camera Manager.

In your Camera Manager's `LateUpdate`:

```cs
if (GameStateManager.GameState == GameState.Set || GameStateManager.GameState == GameState.Playing) {     
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(this.offset.x + ActorManager.Instance.Actor.transform.position.x + 0.8f, 0, -10);
    float cameraMoveAmount = newPosition.x - MainCamera.transform.position.x;
    MainCamera.transform.position = newPosition;
    pathManager.MoveMountains(cameraMoveAmount) 
}
```

Then, in your PathManager, use that moveAmount to change the positions of all of the mountains, as well as where the next one will be created.  After this point is where you should check for any need to show new mountains, not in the PathManager's `LateUpdate`. This is because you need to move the mountains *before* you check to add new ones, and there is no guarantee which happens first if you have them in different `LateUpdate` calls.

Something like this:

```cs
// How fast the mountain layers are going to move in the direction of the camera.    
// 0.0f - will not move with the camera, mountains will slide out of frame at normal speed.
// 1.0f - will move with the camera, no movement will be visible in frame.
public float nearMountainMoveSpeed = 0.5;
public float farMountainMoveSpeed = 0.9f;

. . .

public void MoveMountains(float cameraMoveAmount) {
    float nearMountainParallaxMove = nearMountainMoveSpeed * cameraMoveAmount;
    float farMountainParallaxMove = farMountainMoveSpeed * cameraMoveAmount;

    // Move the near mountains & their next placement
    MountainNearXPosition += nearMountainParallaxMove;
    foreach (GameObject nearMountain in pooledNearMountains) {
        nearMountain.transform.position = nearMountain.transform.position + new Vector3(nearMountainParallaxMove,0f,0f);
    }    

    // Check for new Near Mountain
    if (lastMountainNear != null && GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x > lastMountainNear.transform.position.x) {
        this.GenerateNearMountain();
    }

    // Move the far mountains & their next placement
    MountainFarXPosition += farMountainParallaxMove;
    foreach (GameObject farMountain in pooledFarMountains) {
        farMountain.transform.position = farMountain.transform.position + new Vector3(farMountainParallaxMove,0f,0f);
    }

    // Check for new Far Mountain
    if (lastMountainFar != null && GamePlayCameraManager.Instance.MainCamera.transform.position.x > lastMountainFar.transform.position.x) {
        this.GenerateFarMountain();
    }
}
```

And as an aside, If you end up changing your code and having a single gameobject with all of the farMountains as children and one with all of the nearMountains as children, then you can just move the transform of those parent gameobjects instead of looping through each individual mountain. The amount you would need to move it is the same, of course.

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed answer, but the last line in camera manager is giving the error "An object reference is required to access non-static member `PathManager.MoveMountains(float)"

Comment: it's lowercase `pathManager` because it's a reference to your `PathManager` instance.  You have to add it to your `GamePlayCameraManager`